# User Authentication for flutter web using OpenID Connect? (-> KeyCloak)?

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, web, openid-connect

I'm currently working on a flutter/dart-based webpage (not an app). Now I came to the point that I want the web page to open only if the user has authenticated on my cloud-based Keycloak Server (cloud-iam.com).

There are some openid-connect client packages for flutter available, but most only work for google firebase/aws.. and some others are only working for apps, others are already outdated.

For now, I simply want to use the login frontend offered by the keycloak server.
But I totally failed to bring the available openidc packages to a success... :-(

Does anyone have a suitable package and a reference flutter/dart-application how to authenticate a user using an oidc-identity provider (i.e. keycloak?)

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, do you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try keycloak_flutter package which handles keycloak user authentication for the flutter web only
https://pub.dev/packages/keycloak_flutter

As per this package example
https://github.com/gibahjoe/keycloak_flutter/tree/master/example

you can provide you keycloak realm and clientid details, it'll navigate to your keycloak server for login authentication after that you can allow your app to use the token details provided after login

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, I try this but I face an issue when the user enter his credential after login I did not receive any data from Keycloack. And I use the given example of this plugin